# How to Pass Around Structs Containing Either Pointer Arrays or Static Arrays

Tags: c, struct, types

I am passing around structs containing openGL vertex buffers and data to convencience functions that bind and update dateon the GPU. Right now, I have the following:

```
struct VertexBufferData {
    VertexBuffer vbo;
    ElementBuffer ebo;
    size_t    v_cap;
    size_t    v_count;
    size_t    i_cap;
    size_t    i_count;
    GLfloat*  vertices; // dynamically allocated
    GLuint*   indices; // dynamically allocated
};
```

Yet sometimes I know the sizes for some vertices and indices buffers at compile time, in which case I would like to do this:

```
struct VertexBufferData {
    VertexBuffer  vbo;
    ElementBuffer ebo;
    size_t    v_cap;
    size_t    v_count;
    size_t    i_cap;
    size_t    i_count;
    GLfloat   vertices[SOME_CONST_SIZE_1];
    GLuint    indices[SOME_CONST_SIZE_2];
};
```

The structs are practically identical, but static arrays and pointer/dynamically allocated memory are different and require different types, which means that I would need to duplicate a lot of code (functions and other structs, e.g. `void gl_bind_buffers_and_upload_data(VertexBufferData* vbd, GLenum usage)`
 ) just to support both versions of the struct.

Is there a way to consider both of the structs as the same type or an elegant workaround *without switching to C++'s inheritance (which I am trying to avoid)*. I'd like to keep the data as POD. Template parameterization doesn't solve the problem, but could there be another light way of solving the problem in C++? (I'd be willing to use features that don't use virtual functions).

My first thought would be to create some sort of wrapper entity, but that sounds too complex. Should I just accept having to duplicate code?

Comment: KISS: Just use the pointers throughout.

Comment: I don't think there's any simple way to unify them in C.

Comment: @Barmar In other words, just use heap allocations? I'll probably use a pre-allocated arena so that's feasible.

Comment: Post an example use of `struct VertexBufferData` (style 2).   I suspect   a flag in the`struct VertexBufferData` to indicate if `vertices,indices` are dynamic or not will be sufficient.  Yet a sample use would be illustrative.

Comment: But if you want to be able to pass either type to common functions, you'll probably need to use a `union` of both types. Then you'll need lots of code that switched between the structs based on a discriminator.

Comment: @chux It's mostly to reap the benefits of stack-allocated memory, which can be faster than dynamic allocation.

Comment: @synchronizer Would it be problematic to create arrays on the stack and then assign pointers to them to your structs?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That is what I was doing so far, but it seemed a bit off. The more I think about it though... it might be easiest just to keep everything the same.